# Generate unique cross in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a problem. I don't understand how can I generate unique "cross" for the input.
Here is my input:

```
A, B, C
```

I would like to get:

```
A,B
A,C
B,C
```

What UDF (data-fu, piggybank) can I use to solve this problem?

Comment: Are A, B, C 3 records, or just one bag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is like

```
A
B
C
```

and your want to output:

```
A,B
A,C
B,C
```

You can use `cross` join to get the results. For example:

```
input1 = load 'your_path' as (key: chararray);
input2 = load 'your_path' as (key: chararray);
cross_results = cross input1, input2;
final_results = filter cross_results by input1::key < input2::key;
```

If "A,B,C" are only a bag in one record, you can use `flatten`. For example,

```
-- Assume your input x is something like {A, B, C} in one row
y = foreach x generate flatten($0) as f1, flatten($0) as f2;
final_results = filter y by f1 < f2;
```

As your description is not very exhaustive, I can only provide the above solution. You may need to adapt it.